# How can I get the new height of an item inside a proportionally resized image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-scaling

On a website, I have an image that takes the whole browser window, fixed at its weight. This picture has some objects that have to be clickable, so I draw absolute-positioned links on its respective coordinates. I have an onResize event that resizes them relative to the new window size like this:

```
//org contains img size to get aspect ratio: [originalWidth, originalHeight]
W = area.w*$('.visor img').width()/org[0]
X = area.x*$('.visor img').width()/org[0]
H = area.h*$('.visor img').height()/org[1]
Y = area.y*$(window).width()/$(window).data('originalWidth')
```

So, when you resize the window the area gets correctly resized according to the new image's size, and correctly positioned on X axis, but not the Y axis. It always moves more than the actual resize.

As you can assume, I'm using JQuery for this, but i think the idea is quite understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The markup of how these images and links are layed on the page.

Comment: Just imagine an IMG tag with the same width as your window, and an absolute-positioned DIV floating over it. That div surounds a face in the picture. When you resize your browser, you want the div to follow the face, keeping the face's size and position. Well, I'm getting everything except for the right Y position.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a set of parenthesis (I'm not sure why the other lines seem to work this way, but I would recommend the following change):

```
area.y*$(window).width()/$(window).data('originalWidth')
```

...should be

```
area.y*($(window).width()/$(window).data('originalWidth'))
      / \                                               / \
       |                                                 |
```

You're re-calculating the ratio between the old and new image sizes **on each line**, which is error prone, because the fourth line in your code is trying to do the same ratio calculation as the previous three lines. I would recommend calculating the percentage change ONCE, and multiplying all values by that.

Comment: Did you delete your original message? I was about to tell you I had already done that :P and, not, even with the parenthesis it doesn't works. Also, I'm not at the point of optimization yet. When I get this working I will worry about things like caching calculations into variables.

Comment: I did delete my original answer. After your comments, it seems like I was too far off the mark, so I retracted it. I'm not sure what might be wrong. Is it maybe because you're basing your resize on the width of the window? What if you change only the height of the window - won't that throw things off? Can you post the output of your code's calculations? Perhaps something in there will reveal what's happening. I.e. when orignalHeight = A, resizedHeight = B.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the one-time calculation as an optimization (the amount of processing/memory you'd save would be negligible) , but as a way to reduce duplicate calculations, and as such, the number of places errors could happen.

Comment: If you change the window height, nothing happens; you just reveal more or less the image. Its  anchored to the window width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to with you using width for height? Also, I'm not sure wether getting the height or width from $(window) will do you much good, maybe it's better to get the height and width of the HTML-element.

By the way, isn't it better to use percentages instead of a fixed position? That way it is handled by CSS instead of JS. Not sure if it works though.

Comment: I need to feed the script with actual coordinates from another source, and using percentages would lend me to the same problem: elements inside a resized picture don't get resized in the same proportion as the picture itself.